# quickfix automake makefile installation issues

Tags: c++, makefile, automake, fix-protocol

When trying to install quickfix from [here](http://www.quickfixengine.org/download). I uncompressed the tar.gz file and then in my OSX terminal, I chose the directory that it was uncompressed in and originally had a bit of trouble setting up the config (when running configure) so decided to use the bootstrap, but I got the following when running the bootstrap. Which I think is causing future problems when configuring and making the relevant installation files...Any suggestions on how to fix this and get it installed?

```
quickfix > ./bootstrap
aclocal...  
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
autoheader...
libtoolize...
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `config'.
glibtoolize: linking file `config/ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.in and
glibtoolize: rerunning glibtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
glibtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
automake...
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in:5: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.  For more    info, see:
configure.in:5: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE-invocation
configure.in:14: installing 'config/config.guess'
configure.in:14: installing 'config/config.sub'
configure.in:5: installing 'config/install-sh'
configure.in:5: installing 'config/missing'
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
examples/executor/C++/Makefile.am:10: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
examples/executor/C++/Makefile.am: installing 'config/depcomp'
examples/ordermatch/Makefile.am:17: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
examples/ordermatch/test/Makefile.am:13: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
examples/tradeclient/Makefile.am:10: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/C++/Makefile.am:166: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/C++/test/Makefile.am:40: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/Makefile.am:23: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/python/Makefile.am:61: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
autoconf...
Now run configure with any arguments necessary
```

after this I ran

```
quickfix > ./configure
```

which seemed to run without error after which i wanted to run `make` but got the following errors:

```
2 warnings and 9 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [ut.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

some of the errors look like this:

```
In file included from ut.cpp:27:    
./C++/Utility.h:185:12: error: no member named 'abort' in namespace 'std'
using std::abort;
      ~~~~~^
```

With warnings that look like this:

```
In file included from ut.cpp:50:
C++/test/SessionTestCase.cpp:1178:8: warning: 
      'SuiteSessionTests::resetOnEndTimeFixture::createSession' hides overloaded
      virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  void createSession()
       ^
```

Others include warnings like this:

```
In file included from at.cpp:28:
./at_application.h:110:8: warning: 'MessageCracker::onMessage' hides overloaded
      virtual functions [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  void onMessage( const FIX42::SecurityDefinition& message,
       ^
C++/fix40/MessageCracker.h:63:16: note: hidden overloaded virtual function
      'FIX40::MessageCracker::onMessage' declared here
  virtual void onMessage( const Message&, const FIX::SessionID& )
               ^
```

Comment: did you run 'now' configure?

Comment: yes...so the `./configure` command works fine, but when running make afterwards, i get the following...`2 warnings and 9 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [ut.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: has this issue been resolved?